# How to iterate over 'Row' values in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have this data as output when i perform `timeStamp_df.head()` in pyspark:

```
Row(timeStamp='ISODate(2020-06-03T11:30:16.900+0000)', timeStamp='ISODate(2020-06-03T11:30:16.900+0000)', timeStamp='ISODate(2020-06-03T11:30:16.900+0000)', timeStamp='ISODate(2020-05-03T11:30:16.900+0000)', timeStamp='ISODate(2020-04-03T11:30:16.900+0000)')
```

My expected output is:

```
+-------------------------------+
|timeStamp                      |
+-------------------------------+
|2020-06-03T11:30:16.900+0000|
|2020-06-03T11:30:16.900+0000|
|2020-06-03T11:30:16.900+0000|
|2020-05-03T11:30:16.900+0000|
|2020-04-03T11:30:16.900+0000|
+-------------------------------+
```

I tried to first use `.collect()` method and want to iterate

```
rows_list = timeStamp_df.collect()
print(rows_list)
```

It's output is:

```
[Row(timeStamp='ISODate(2020-06-03T11:30:16.900+0000)', timeStamp='ISODate(2020-06-03T11:30:16.900+0000)', timeStamp='ISODate(2020-06-03T11:30:16.900+0000)', timeStamp='ISODate(2020-05-03T11:30:16.900+0000)', timeStamp='ISODate(2020-04-03T11:30:16.900+0000)')]
```

Just to see the values I am using the print statement:

```
def print_row(row):
    print(row.timeStamp)


for row in rows_list:
    print_row(row)
```

But I am getting the single output as it only iterates once in list:

```
ISODate(2020-06-03T11:30:16.900+0000)
```

How can I iterate over the data of Row in pyspark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You cannot repeat keyword arguments when creating a `Row`.
2. A valid `Row` is iterable:

```
row = Row(a=10, b=20, c=30)
print([column for column in row])

[10, 20, 30]
```